# Naemon stopping itself

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esx

I'm currently running Naemon on a CentOS7 which as you can read it in the title, stop himself for some reasons I don't get. This problem started when I tried to add some check for monitor my Esx's and my Vcenter.

For your information, I'm running the web gui Thruk with this Naemon trough the livestatus method.

Here are the most exhaustive logs that I can find :

Naemon.log :

```
[1438693212] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX : Etat général' on host 'SWE-ESX' was out of bounds.
[1438693215] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_cpu_usage' on host 'srv_esx_5' was out of bounds.
[1438693216] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_NET' on host 'srv_esx_1' was out of bounds.
[1438693216] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_IO_All' on host 'srv_esx_3' was out of bounds.
[1438693222] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'Vcenter : Etat volume VM' on host 'srv_vcenter' was out of bounds.
[1438693223] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX : Etat général' on host 'srv_esx_1' was out of bounds.
[1438693224] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_IO_All' on host 'srv_esx_2' was out of bounds.
[1438693224] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX : Etat général' on host 'srv_esx_4' was out of bounds.
[1438693227] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_NET' on host 'srv_esx_3' was out of bounds.
[1438693230] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_mem_All' on host 'SWE-ESX' was out of bounds.
[1438693241] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_NET' on host 'srv_esx_5' was out of bounds.
[1438693241] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'Vcenter : Etat réseau' on host 'srv_vcenter' was out of bounds.
[1438693245] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_runtime_All' on host 'srv_esx_2' was out of bounds.
[1438693248] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX : Etat temperature' on host 'srv_esx_1' was out of bounds.
[1438693248] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'Vcenter : Etat CPU' on host 'srv_vcenter' was out of bounds.
[1438693249] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX : Etat général' on host 'srv_esx_3' was out of bounds.
[1438693252] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'ESX_runtime_All' on host 'srv_esx_3' was out of bounds.
```

Then nothing, the service just stop without telling me anything.

Thruk.log :

```
[2015/08/04 12:21:10][SRV-NAEMON][ERROR][Thruk.Controller.error] srvprod: ERROR: failed to connect - Connection refused. (/var/cache/naemon/live)
[2015/08/04 12:32:48][SRV-NAEMON][INFO][Thruk.Controller.cmd] [admin][srvprod] cmd: COMMAND [1438684368] SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;srv_esx_4;ESX_runtime_All;1438684368
[2015/08/04 13:09:57][SRV-NAEMON][ERROR][Thruk.Backend.Manager] failed setting states by local check
[2015/08/04 13:32:14][SRV-NAEMON][ERROR][Thruk.Controller.Root] Caught exception in Thruk::Controller::status->index "failed to connect - Connection refused at lib/Monitoring/Livestatus/Class/Lite.pm line 321."
[2015/08/04 13:32:14][SRV-NAEMON][ERROR][Thruk.Controller.error] No Backend available
[2015/08/04 13:32:14][SRV-NAEMON][ERROR][Thruk.Controller.error] on page: http://192.168.1.41/thruk/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all&_=1438687952893
```

When I try to execute my ESX checkhere is what I got:

```
[root@SRV-NAEMON vmware-vsphere-cli-distrib]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl -H 192.168.1.141 -f /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pwd/srv_esx_4 -l net
Constant subroutine Monitoring::Plugin::Functions::OK redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/constant.pm line 171.
Constant subroutine Monitoring::Plugin::Functions::WARNING redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/constant.pm line 171.
Constant subroutine Monitoring::Plugin::Functions::CRITICAL redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/constant.pm line 171.
Constant subroutine Monitoring::Plugin::Functions::UNKNOWN redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/constant.pm line 171.
Constant subroutine Monitoring::Plugin::Functions::DEPENDENT redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/constant.pm line 171.
Subroutine _fake_exit redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 50.
Subroutine _use_die redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 54.
Subroutine get_shortname redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 56.
Subroutine max_state redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 70.
Subroutine max_state_alt redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 79.
Subroutine plugin_exit redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 89.
Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::die(), qualify as such or use & at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 150.
Subroutine _plugin_exit redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 141.
Subroutine plugin_die redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 160.
Subroutine die redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 185.
Subroutine convert redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 193.
Subroutine check_messages redefined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Monitoring/Plugin/Functions.pm line 206.
Bareword "UNKNOWN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 545.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 552.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 610.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 672.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 722.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 750.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 788.
Bareword "UNKNOWN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 801.
Bareword "UNKNOWN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 805.
Bareword "UNKNOWN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 809.
Bareword "CRITICAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 814.
Global symbol "%STATUS_TEXT" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 2047.
Global symbol "%STATUS_TEXT" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 2061.
Global symbol "%STATUS_TEXT" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 2115.
Global symbol "%STATUS_TEXT" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl line 2198.
Execution of /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_vmware_api.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I did install the vmware by following this linkand apapt it to my configuration/monitoring system: http://www.smnet.fr/icinga/icinga-sdk.html

Does anyone have any ideas?